# how can i loop through an array within an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to loop through an array of objects named tier1. 
what I get is this:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

My code looks something like this:

```
module.exports.getTier1= function(curUser, callback){       
    for (var i = 0; i < curUser.tier1.length; i++) {
        var val = curUser.tier1[i];
        console.log("index: " + i + "   val: " + val);
    }
};

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        index:true
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    tier1: [Tier1]

});
```

Comment: Try, `curUser.tier1[0].length`

Comment: Try `console.log(curUser)` - do you get what you were expecting?  e.g. is `tier1` actually a property of `curUser` that contains an array - or is the object not quite what you thought it was?

Comment: You should first check if your curUser object has an property called "tier1". Try increasing logs to determine structure of curUser object that you are getting.